# How to create a simple JavaScript pagination? (like "see more results")

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pagination

As the title says, I've been searching the whole internet for a good solution using simple javascript/jquery for this kind of pagination.

I've got this:

```php
<div class="gallery">
<?php
    if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
?>
     <a id="<?php echo $row['Ano']; ?>" class="thumbsObras" href="">
        <img src="<?php echo "includes/autores/thumbs/".$row['path']; ?>" width="225" height="225" />
     </a>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Basically, the gallery is the container of the repeat zone with the data from the DB. It creates several images.

I wish to have a button that says "see more 12 results" and pressing it automatically displays the next 12 results, so it would have 24 results on the screen. Then if the user wants even more, there's the button again (like App Store in the iPhone), and so on. iIs that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but your question is very broad, what specific part of the creation of a pagination are you stuck on ?

Comment: I can't start with it, I searched for a few javascript pagination tutorials but they're all for tables, anyone knows a good tutorial that is like what I described?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's a table or lists or whatever, the HTML is just formatting noise in this case.